# Google Analytics: No stats from DMZ network

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-analytics

We recently moved our web servers off the network. Since moving to an internal DMZ Google Analytics has stopped tracking our sites. Our networking guys have reviewed the firewall logs and say that we are not blocking outbound HTTP traffic to Google Analytics. They also say we are not using a proxy.  See part of the log below. Can anyone give us a pointer of why it would have stopped tracking. I am not a network guy so I don't really know what to look for in the logs.

GET /_*utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.4&utms=1&utmn=1730648486&utmhn=www.google.com&utmcs=utf-8&utmsr=1440x900&utmvp=788x475&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=-&utmdt=Google%20Analytics%20Official%20Website%20-%20Web%20Analytics%20%26%20Reporting%20%E2%80%93%20Google%20Analytics&utmhid=629406946&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fanalytics%2F&utmht=1377611588271&utmac=UA-10005-1&utmcc=*_utma%3D173272373.1488865239.1377611588.1377611588.1377611588.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D173272373.1377611588.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=qKC~ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.google.com/analytics/
Accept-Language: en-us
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: www.google-analytics.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser will make a request for __utm.gif (or /collect) if the GA code is loading properly - please copy and paste one of the requests into your question.

The __utm.gif request you pasted is copied from the Google Analytics website, not from your own website.

Comment: I have updated my question with that information.

Comment: How do I get the information you are looking for?  I need to tell our networking guys where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Open your site in the browser, open developer tools, find a request to `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?`, and check if the status code is 200:

[image: Google analytics request]